# Настройка WCF конфига

Tags: c#, imap

Есть конфиг WCF службы по TCP

```
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MAKOTA.SERVER.Service.MainService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
        name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="SERVER.Service.IMainService">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
        name="MexTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/MService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Создал ссылку на службу в клиенте пытаюсь подключиться, на локальной машине все работает. Однако когда я перемещаю на сервер и меняю localhost на конкретный IP подключиться не могу. Выскакивает ошибка что удаленный компьютер оборвал соединение.

Есть вообще какой-то шаблон настройки?

Comment: Привет, А firewall смотрел?

Comment: Да в том числе сетевой экран тормозил пакеты,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в строке подключения я использовал авторизацию windows,а надо было SQL.